# PHP SQL Query with three variables in the where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a snapshot of the code I am struggling with in php. I have a database object, an activity class and a booking form. From the booking form I pass three variables to the check availability method which queries the database. The var dump is returning:

```
object(DB)#3 (6) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=>
object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(99) "SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE name =
'Archery' AND act_date = '05/01/2015' AND time_from = '10.00'" } ["_error":"DB":private]=>
bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(0) { } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(0)
["_data":"DB":private]=> NULL }
```

This makes me think that the query is not returning something yet the query does return records in MySQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**1. Calling method to check availability:**

```
if($activity->checkDateTimeAvailability($act_name, $date, $time) === false)){
    // Do something here
}

//Method to check if the activity is available at the requested date and time:

public function checkDateTimeAvailability($name, $date, $time) {
    $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE name = 
    '$name' AND act_date = '$date' AND time_from = '$time'");
    if(!empty($result)){
        echo "query successful";
        var_dump($result);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

//Generic query method:

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    // reset to ensure an error from a previous query is not returned. 
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Have you logged in to the database with a username and password?

Comment: No there is no username or password.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, NEVER use variables in a SQL query, use prepare statements.

To you question. The `PDO::query` method returns a `PDOStatement` object. With this object you can **fetch** the result from the database server.

Just call `$this->_db->query('Your SQL query')->fetchAll()` and you get your rows.

Comment: Sorry Markus I am new to PHP could you possibly demonstrate how to write the querying using a prepared statement.

Comment: // Method to check if the activity is available at the requested date and time.
public function checkDateTimeAvailability($name, $date, $time) {
    $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE name = ?   AND act_date = ? AND time_from = ?", array($name, $date, $time));
  $result = $this->_db->fetch();
 } Then added the pdo fetchAll() method into my DB class but I am still not getting anywhere.

Comment: Sure here you go:

<?php

public function checkDateTimeAvailability($name, $date, $time) 
{
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM `activity` WHERE name = ? AND act_date = ? AND time_from = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$name, $date, $time]);
    
    return null !== $stmt->fetchColumn();
}

I optimize your query, because you currently fetch the completly database to check, if an result exist or not. This will be a problem, if you have an large dataset.

I hope it helps!